# "Cannot locate WordPress root directory," error while updating WordPress or installing any plugins

Tags: apache, wordpress, centos

I am running WordPress on a CentOS server with Apache and Mysql and it was running smoothly a couple of days ago but when I am trying to install any plugin or update WordPress, it gives the error with the exact statement "Unable to locate WordPress root directory".

Any suggestions are welcome because I need to install a few plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by the wrong FTP username being given (not an incorrect password – that would be trapped nicely by wordpress – but the username).

I guess this isn’t something that is going to happen often – moving a server and so changing the FTP username – but I’m glad I thought to read around before spending hours diagnosing the server.

Comment: the login credentials are correct and i've verified them but it's still occuring.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/autoupdate-unable-to-locate-wordpress-root-directory

Comment: http://www.incomesensor.com/solve-the-error-unable-to-locate-wordpress-content-directory-when-change-host/

Comment: None of this is helping. i need any more suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the web host you are using. If you are hosting it on a free web host it could be somewhat unstable. If you really want to test wordpress out to see how it would word if it did word correctly, try using WAMP.
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: No, I am using a VPS from digital Ocean and i configured it myself. This is not a free server, I am paying $40/month to keep it running. So, please tell me what to do?

Comment: Did you use quick install or did you install wordpress manually. @NishantDixit

Comment: I installed it manually since digital ocean doesnot provide with quick install for wordpress